# Can't display object details in deletion confirmation dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, confirm, commandbutton

Here is my commandButton inside a datatable column which job is to delete the associated line object:

```
   <p:column style="width:6%;text-align:center"
   headerText="Delete">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close"
     title="Delete release #{release.name}"
     actionListener="#{releaseBean.deleteRelease(release)}"
     process="@this" update=":display :form2:releaseList">
        <p:confirm
          header="Confirm deleting release #{release.name}"
          message="Are you really sure you want to delete release #{release.name}?"
          icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>
   </p:column>
```

I want the name of the release to be displayed in the delete confirm message (Are you really sure you want to delete release "XYZ" ?).. But the problem is that the name of the release "XYZ" is not displayed nor in the header of `<p:confirm>` neither in the message; but it's displayed in the `<p:commandButton>` title.

What have I done wrong? Thank you.

---

EDIT:

I tried to modify the commandButton and add the `setPropertyActionListener`:

```
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close"
         title="Delete release #{release.name}"
         actionListener="#{releaseBean.deleteRelease(release)}"
         process="@this" update=":display :form2:releaseList">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener
         target="#{gestionReleaseBean.selectedRelease}"
         value="#{release}" />            
         <p:confirm
              header="Confirm deleting release #{release.name}"
              message="Are you really sure you want to delete release #{release.name}?"
              icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

and in the bean I added the property `selectedRelease` and it's getter/setter.

It didn't work...

Comment: Is the commandButton itself ajax-updated, i.e. does the `update` attribute of commandButton contain the id of a component embedding it?

Comment: the update concerns a `<p:growl id="display">` and the whole `<p:datatable>` (in which is the button) in order to suppress the freshly deleted line. Why?

Comment: Is it possible to use a standalone `dialog` or `confirmDialog` with an attribute from the bean instead of a `p:confirm` with a global `confirmDialog`?

Comment: Seems like you've stumbled on a possible bug @Siho. I've tested and confirmed it myself, the `<p:confirm/>` cannot evaluate the local variable of the datatable. It appears to be able to evaluate only values that are available during page build, not during page render. What this means is that only a value that's available in your backing bean, before the datatable is rendered, will make it into the markup. You can check the generated javascript yourself to confirm that the js responsible for the popup itself has empty values where your `var` should be

Comment: @rion18 how to do that, you mean like this (from PF user guide) `<h:form>
<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('cd').show()" />
<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure about destroying the world?"
header="Initiating destroy process" severity="alert"
widgetVar="cd">
<p:commandButton value="Yes Sure" actionListener="#{buttonBean.destroyWorld}"
update="messages" oncomplete="PF('cd').hide()"/>
<p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="PF('cd').hide();" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>`

Comment: Kinda... I was talking about having a variable called `selectedObject` (or something) and referencing `#{bean.selectedObject.name}` from the dialog...

Comment: and how to set the value of that `selectedObject`?

Comment: Adding an `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedObject}" value="#{release}" />` inside your `p:commandButton`

Comment: @rion18 It didn't work :( I edited my question to specify what I've done

Comment: In this case `p:confirm` will not work. You need to create a dialog or a confirmDialog outside of the table and reference that component.

Comment: try `<p:confirm header="Confirm deleting release #{gestionReleaseBean.selectedRelease.name}" message="Are you really sure you want to delete release #{gestionReleaseBean.selectedRelease.name}?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>`

Comment: But this is exactly the code I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: No, my confirm dialog uses `#{gestionReleaseBean.selectedRelease.name}?` and yours takes `#{release.name}`...

Comment: I just tried that and it still doesn't display the release name

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind some extra code lines then you can achieve this  as below,

First place a dialog out side datatable

```
<p:dialog modal="true" header="Confirm" widgetVar="wgc" >
 <h:outputText id="msg" />
 <h:inputHidden id="idh" value="#{releaseBean.id}" />
 <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{bean.delete()}" />
 <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" onclick="PF('wgc').hide()" />
</p:dialog>
```

in your javascript section add this

```
function confirm(id,name){
 document.getElementById('msg').innerHtml='Are you sure to delete ' +  name;
 document.getElementById('idh').value=id;
 PF('wgc').show();
}
```

and then in datatable delete button

```
<p:commandButon type="button" 
                value="Delete" 
                onclick="confirm(#{release.id},'#{release.name}')" />
```

Comment: Thank you alessadro for your reponse, but I don't have a javascript section, and I don't know where to put it in my xhtml page.. Can you clarify this point for me please ?

Comment: you can add the above code inside <script>  </script> tags anywhere in your xhtml page, but it is good to keep js just above the body closing tag </h:body>

Comment: and dont forget to implement delete method in ur bean, i just showed u how to displayselected item's name and pass id to the bean

Comment: "but it is good to keep js just above the body closing tag </h:body>" ? How is that ??

Comment: I have this structure in my xml file --> <body>
  <ui:define name="metadata"></ui:define>
  <ui:define name="content"></ui:define>
 </body>

Comment: Where am I supposed to add <script> tag thus ?

Comment: You surely know where is the end of your body tag if 'content ' section is the last defined, then it will be <ui:define name="content">---some codes---    <script></script></ui:define>